# Associating S3 object with user ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using `createPresignedPost` method to let users upload an image to S3, after which I am planning to dispatch a notification to trigger an AWS Lambda function to process this image (check content type for example).

At the same time I want to get who uploaded this image, and with that data I want to save the image S3 key and uploader ID in a database. I have thought about getting this data by metadata, but it is not secure. The current solution that I have is that I will encrypt the data, put it in image metadata and decrypt it in the Lambda function, but is there any other more common way that I am not seeing?

Comment: You can add a `starts-with` limitation with something like a user ID to the presigned request so the user must use that prefix on their upload, and map that prefix to the user uploading the data.

Comment: How are your users authenticating and obtaining their unique identifier?

Comment: Hey, auth identifier is jwt token